# AZURE_KEY_VAULT provider in SSRS

Tags: encryption, azure, visual-studio-2017, ssrs

I've recently set up Always Encryption on an on-prem SQL Server db with the column master key in Azure Key Vault. If I SELECT from the table in SSMS with 'Column Encryption Setting=Enabled' I can read the column in plain text so _I'm pretty confident* the encryption is functioning as expected.

Now I want to throw and SSRS report over that table in Visual Studio 2017. My data source uses integrated security and I've added 'Column Encryption Setting=Enabled' to the connection string but SSRS can't decrypt the column. I get the following error:

```
[rsMissingFieldInDataSet] The dataset ‘DataSet1’ contains a definition for the Field ‘Number’. This field is missing from the returned result set from the data source.
[rsErrorReadingDataSetField] The dataset ‘DataSet1’ contains a definition for the Field ‘Number’. The data extension returned an error during reading the field. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Failed to decrypt column 'Number'.
Failed to decrypt a column encryption key. Invalid key store provider name: 'AZURE_KEY_VAULT'. A key store provider name must denote either a system key store provider or a registered custom key store provider. Valid system key store provider names are: 'MSSQL_CERTIFICATE_STORE', 'MSSQL_CNG_STORE', 'MSSQL_CSP_PROVIDER'. Valid (currently registered) custom key store provider names are: . Please verify key store provider information in column master key definitions in the database, and verify all custom key store providers used in your application are registered properly. ---> System.ArgumentException: Failed to decrypt a column encryption key. Invalid key store provider name: 'AZURE_KEY_VAULT'. A key store provider name must denote either a system key store provider or a registered custom key store provider. Valid system key store provider names are: 'MSSQL_CERTIFICATE_STORE', 'MSSQL_CNG_STORE', 'MSSQL_CSP_PROVIDER'. Valid (currently registered) custom key store provider names are: . Please verify key store provider information in column master key definitions in the database, and verify all custom key store providers used in your application are registered properly.
```

It doesn't look like Nuget is supported in SSRS solutions and I've installed every Azure prereq and extension I can think of to Visual Studio. Is there a way to register AZURE_KEY_VAULT as a key store provider for SSRS?